# Null pointer exception, "Attempt to read from field on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am making an app in which the user types in a list of tasks, and that list is saved to an array. Each task in the array is an instance of the `Assignment` class. However, I realized that in java it is not possible to add an element to an array after the array is created. So, what I did was I created an array called `tasks` which consisted of many null values: `Assignment[]tasks = {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};`. When I want to add a task to the array, I just replace the next null value with the object. However, I also need to have an array of just the tasks, with no null values. So I created an array called `full_tasks` for all of the elements that aren't null:

```
for (Assignment task: tasks) {
    if (task != null) {
        realLength += 1;
    }
}

Assignment[] full_tasks = new Assignment[realLength];

for (int i=0; i <= full_tasks.length - 1; i++) {
        full_tasks[i] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time);
}
```

So now, the `full_tasks` array should be an array of all the tasks, none of which are null, right? However, when I run the app, it can't launch the activity, an error it says is caused by a null pointer exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.lb.homeworkappv11.Assignment.name' on a null object reference
        at com.example.lb.homeworkappv11.Schedule.sortTasks(Schedule.java:64)
```

The line that the error points to is:

```
full_tasks[i] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time);
```

I'm still not totally sure what a null object reference is, but I think it means that one of the elements in the `full_tasks` array is null. Would that be correct? And if it is, what can I do to make sure that the `full_tasks` array is **only** the non-null elements in the `tasks` array?

Thank you so much!

**Edit:** the constructor function for the assignment class is:

```
public Assignment(String name, int days, int time) {
    this.name = name;
    this.days_due = days;
    this.time = time;
    this.toSortBy = "nothing";
}
```

Comment: Your "name" variable inside the Assignment is null. Can you post the code of the constructor you're using?

Comment: I added the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `null` reference is just that `null`. In your code it is `tasks[i].name` where you try to call `name` on `tasks[i]` so `tasks[i]` is `null`.

There is one scenario I can think of, where your code would definitely throw a `NullPointerException`.
So, I will assume your tasks array can look looks like this:

```
tasks = [task0, null, task2, task3, null, task5]
```

Then `full_tasks` will have a size of 4 but

```
for (int i=0; i <= full_tasks.length - 1; i++) {
        full_tasks[i] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time);
}
```

will throw a *NPE* as soon as `i == 1` because `tasks[1]` is `null`.

So, if you want to fill `full_tasks` with only non-null tasks make sure you got the right indexes of `tasks`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer was very helpful. I altered my for loop so that it only takes the non-null elements, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's what I think**

You are just finding the number elements that are not `null`. You don't know where in the array thest `null`'s are present.

Suppose ONLY the first element is `null`. So `realLength` will be 7. The latter `for` loop runs from `i=0` to `i=7`. When `i=0`, `tasks[i].name` tries to access the `name` field of the first element; but your first element happens to be null`. That's where things go wrong.

**Solution:**

There are a number of solutions. The most efficient one I can think of uses an `ArrayList`.

To get around using arrays, you should store the indices of all elements that are not `null`. That's one way.

Here's another:

```
for (Assignment task: tasks) {
  if (task != null) {
    realLength += 1;
  }
}
Assignment[] full_tasks = new Assignment[realLength];
int count = 0;
for (Assignment task: tasks) {
  if (task != null) {
    full_tasks[count] = new Assignment(task.name, tasks.days_due, task.time);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "tasks" list is empty. Make sure its get populated or put a null check
like :

```
if(tasks[i] !=null) {

full_tasks[i] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due,  tasks[i].time);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of null as something not exists, for example when you try to get `task.name`, where task is **null**, you get error, because you try to get name from some something which does not even exists.

Actually what your code is doing now is check how many non-null items in the original array, and try to extract the extra the first n items from the array to a new array.

i.e. if the list is `{null, null, non-null, non-null}`, it has 2 non-null item, however your code wrongly extracts the list of the first 2 items which are `{null, null}`

**Edit, to actually do what you want:**

```
ArrayList<Assignment> fullTaskList = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
for (Assignment task: tasks) {
    if (task != null) {
        fullTaskList.add(task);
    }
}
//optional
Assignment[] fullTasks = fullTaskList.toArray(new Assignment[fullTaskList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is here:

```
(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time).
```

Although you're counting the real size, there could be some null value in between that is causing it to be get a null object from the list tasks[i].

---

A good idea to solve this is by using a List instead of an Array. A List can be increased or decreased as you want, you just have to add or remove an item of your object type. For example:

```
List<Assignment> list = new ArrayList<>();
Assignment assignment1 = new Assignment(etc.);
list.add(assignment1);
list.get(0) //-> returns the Assignment object that you added.
```

Then you can use `list.size()` to get the size to know how many items are there, or to remove the last item. And you would have no problems to add new items to the list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to copy and compact the `tasks` array into the `full_tasks` array (removing the null elements), but you are doing this partially incorrect since you are accessing `tasks[i]` in the second loop without checking whether its is null.

Instead of:

```
for (int i=0; i <= full_tasks.length - 1; i++) {
    full_tasks[i] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time);
}
```

you could write something like this:

```
for (int i = 0, f = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i] != null) {
        full_tasks[f] = new Assignment(tasks[i].name, tasks[i].days_due, tasks[i].time);
        f++;
    }
}
```

But then again to solve your original problem, regarding the fact that you cannot add any elements to an array, I suggest to use an [`ArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a simple array. This allows you to add items with `ArrayList.add(assignment)` and remove them again with `ArrayList.remove(index)`.